# Abaqus Python console linked to Spyder

Tags: python, spyder, abaqus

I was wondering whether it is possible to connect external Python console to Spyder app. I use Abaqus which has Python console implemented and it will be a lot easier for me to write and run the script in one app.

It should be possible as there is already an example on how to run Abaqus Python within Visual Studio [Link](https://yhtian.wordpress.com/2017/04/04/a-fully-working-ide-with-abaqus-python/)

Also, there is *Connect to existing kernel* option in Spyder, but I have not found any useful example on how to use it.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To do what you want, you need to:

1. Install a package called `ipykernel` in your Abaqus Python (don't know what that is, sorry).
2. Open Spyder, go to

   `Tools > Preferences > Python interpreter`

   and select the Python executable of your Abaqus Python (e.g. `C:\Abaqus\python.exe`)
3. Start a new IPython console in Spyder to use Abaqus Python inside Spyder.

The first step is certainly the hardest one, but if Abaqus comes with `pip`, it should be as simple as running `pip install ipykernel` with it.